# How to verify if executable is running

Tags: linux, bash

I have a linux script when this script is executed it has to do the below actions.

1. exec1 should be started.
2. if exec1 is running then only start  exe2
3. if exec1 is terminated exe2 should also be terminated.

This is my script which I have written.  The issue  is

`if ! pgrep -f exe2 or if ps aux| grep -v grep | grep exe2;`
it is not finding exe2 when it is running . What is the issue here, how do I fix it?

```
xcute=false
while true; do
    if pgrep -f exec1 > /dev/null; then
        echo "I am in first if"    
        #if ! pgrep -f exe2 > /dev/null; then-- not working
        # if ps aux| grep -v grep | grep exe2---> not working
        echo "exe2 running
        if [ "$xcute"  = false ]; then 
            xcute=true
            sudo -E  ./exe2
        fi
    fi
    else
        echo "exec1 is not running, close exec2"
        sudo -E kill $(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep exe2 | awk '{print $2}')    
        exit 
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

`if ! pgrep -f exe2 or  if ps aux | grep -v grep | grep exe2` is not giving exe2 when it is running.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: You're testing for `exe2`, not `exec2`, and missing quotes at the end of `echo "exe2 running`. As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Btw, if you don't want to use `pgrep` for some reason then do `ps aux | grep '[e]xe2'` instead of `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep exe2`.

Comment: This might look like a stupid comment but instead of `echo "exe2 running`, shouldn't you have `echo "exe2 running"` (with an extra double quote at the end)?

Comment: @Dominique- thank for pointing the mistake corrected the error.

Comment: This is exactly what `systemd` is for. Define units for `exec1` and `exec2` with appropriate dependencies between them. Manual parsing of output from `ps` is not just broken and wrong (in terms of atomicity), but also notoriously inefficient and unreliable.